# Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported

Tags: google-bigquery

I have hundreds of queries powering dashboards at my company that have worked for years but broke overnight a couple days ago giving the error:

> Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Below is an example of the type of query that has the issue. Obviously the WHERE condition is the problem. Is this type of query really no longer going to be supported? Will all queries with this syntax now need to be converted to use an INNER JOIN? This is a huge change that has really impacted our analytics.

```
-- standardSQL
SELECT 
  accounts,
  monthly_timestamp
FROM 
  `custom_query_ingestion.accounts_monthly`
WHERE 
  monthly_timestamp <= (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP(date)) FROM `historical_data.historical_revenue`)
```

Comment: For such a question you should better create a public issue tracker for the BQ engineering team, and reference the link here. You may get faster answer using the issue tracker. You should add sample job IDs for both cases if you still have. https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I still can't figure out if this is a bug or if BigQuery genuinely no longer wishes to support queries with this syntax

Comment: @StephanieG I'm not a BigQuery guru, but you might be able to rewrite this query as a cross join with the subquery which finds the max timestamp.  Probably not the best solution, but something to perhaps try.

Comment: Stephanie [posted the bug on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71699514), and someone from the BigQuery team should be able to help resolve the issue.

Comment: @StephanieG I see you are new here. Post as an answer below, and in a few days you can mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a LEFT JOIN on an UNNESTed array constant inside historical_revenue:

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    product
  FROM 
    UNNEST(['Item1','Item2','Item3']) AS product
) AS nonrecurring
ON nonrecurring.product = revenue.product_item
```

Rewriting as a CASE WHEN statement resolved the issue